# Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error]

Tags: oracle, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

I am using the SSAS to develop the tabular model. I am able to extract the data from the database. However, when I try to deploy I keep on getting this error.

Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.  '.

I have tried many solution like:

1. Check my database connection
2. Check the datatype in the table

However, none of the solution works.

Is there a way to find the issue with the Object reference not set to an instance of an object error?

Comment: I assume you did not install the OLE DB / ODBC driver. Ensure you have the right architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit) and version of driver matches the version of the Oracle Client.

Comment: I often get that error after deploying, and almost always the deploy succeeded. This is just one of the many reasons for moving our development from Visual Studio to Power BI Desktop and/or Tabular Editor. You could confirm the deploy by checking properties on the database from SSMS or querying against the model.